# regular expression in perl replacing and hyphenize a part of a string in a source file

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace all occurrences of this pattern

```
new Window.MyElement();
```

with

```
document.createElement('my-element');
```

Note that MyElement can be any Camelized element name

What might be the regex that I need to use in my shell to run e.g.

```
perl -pi -e '....' my-sourcefile.js
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -i -CSD -pe'
  s{new Window\.(\w+)\(\);}{
     "document.createElement(\x27".(
     $1 =~ s/(\p{Lu})/-\l$1/gr =~ s/^-//r
     )."\x27);"
  }eg
' my-sourcefile.js
```

or

```
perl -i -CSD -MString::CamelCase=decamelize -pe'  # Only supports ASCII names
  s{new Window\.(\w+)\(\);}{
     "document.createElement(\x27".(
     decamelize($1) =~ s/_/-/rg
     )."\x27);"
  }eg
' my-sourcefile.js
```

The line breaks are present for readability, but they can be omitted without causing any problems.

Comment: @melpomene, Added to answer, though its result needs fixing because it produces underscores instead of hyphens.

Comment: @melpomene, Note that using `decamelize` makes the code longer, and restricts the names to ASCII.